# How to download in-between videos from Youtube playlist using pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

Suppose there are 10 videos in a playlist. It's simple to download the whole playlist, that is 1 to 10 videos, using a couple of pytube commands. How can we download, suppose 6 to 10? I am using 3.6.5 version.

I am currently using this code:

```
from pytube import Playlist
pl = Playlist("url")
pl.download_all('location')
```

Comment: pytube is no longer maintained, consider using pytube3 instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to individually get each URL.

Try the following

```
from pytube import Playlist, YouTube

pl = Playlist("url")
pl.populate_video_urls()

for u in pl.video_urls[5:]:
    YouTube(u).streams.first().download()
```